# Functional differences between .class, .jar and .java (class) file in eclipse?

Tags: java, class, jar

What are the functional differences between a .class file, a .jar file, and a .java file that defines a class structure in eclipse and when is it appropriate to use each file type?

Comment: because everyone who programmed java for a while should know the difference **very** well. And btw one google search for "java .class file" already yields a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) that pretty much explanes .java & .class files. BTW I'm not one of the downvoters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple language mechanic which is easily found through numerous search results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `.java` file contains Java code.

A `.class` file is the `.java` file compiled

A `.jar` file is an executable java package.

Eclipse compiles `.java` files to create `.class` files and you can package them in an executable `.jar` file.

Comment: If you think it's the correct answer mark it as such please.